# How to stop spammer spoofing my domain for emails

Tags: email, smtp, spam, spf, g-suite

I've scanned all my code and even changed the passwords to my google apps account such that the SMTP password has changed. However, spammers are still sending emails from June24-eBay-USA-contactmsg-6153642111@redacted.com and the email is phishing attack too. I do not want my domain flagged for spam.

I only send emails through google's SMTP servers. I have the free google apps (grandfathered).

I believe I have SPF records and everything I can do to try and prevent this but it's still happening. What is more frustrating is that Google is emailing me `Delivery Status Notification (Failure)` saying the emails can't be sent to a lot of emails, so it's spamming my business email.

I tried to use google app's `Reports > Email Log Search` to see if the spammer is going through my SMTP to send these emails but it always gives an error `No messages found. Please contact the sender for further investigation`. However, I suspect they are spoofing and aren't going through my SMTP?

**What can I do to prevent this?** 

I can't contact Google because I am on the free grandfathered tier

PS: If it helps to look at my SPF records, please check  i m v u - e . com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail for your domain seems to be hosted in Google itself. Configure DKIM and DMARC for your domain in addition to SPF, as per Google manuals:

- [Set up DKIM to prevent email spoofing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en)
- [Add your DMARC record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466563?hl=en)

Note, as is said in DMARC manual, SPF and DKIM must be finished first.

This is the best you can do. This wouldn't prevent spoofing (that's impossible), but other servers will be able to filter out spoofed mail better.

Comment: Hello, I already have DMARC, SPF and DKIM. Most of the spam is being sent to custom mail servers like solvay.com and .edu emails.  I believe the big email providers (google, yahoo, etc) all correctly reject their spam

Comment: Your DMARC policy is now set to "none" which means it is disabled. You need to change it either to "quarantine" or "reject", i.e. DMARC record must say e.g. "p=reject" (amongst other settings).

I can't tell if your DKIM works unless you send mail to me. There are services like mail-tester.com who generate one time email where you send test mails and then they report back what they think about it. Try them!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my dmarc and seem to pass pretty good. See https://www.mail-tester.com/test-9xohuqas5

I'll give it a few days and see if the spam reduces and accept this as an answer

Comment: Been a few days, they stopped and I got a lot of reports from DMARC. Thanks for your help